# Blender Geometry Nodes - Stitch test Problem

Tags: geometry-nodes

While there is no problem on the horizontal path while trying to sew in the blender geometry nodes, but [image]there is a problem on the vertical path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also align the $Z$ axis to the curve normal using the previously aligned axis as pivot:

[image]

With this, you just need to adjust the tilt of the curve's points:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much :)