# How to orient instances on a curve towards next point and not along tangent with geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to intance objects along a curve, but every setup I find uses the tangent of the curve, this is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: image depicting what I'm trying to achieve].

I've already tried these methods [Method 1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/228629/how-to-orient-a-point-to-the-next-one-with-geometry-node-curve-follow) [Method 2](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/267017/blender-geometry-nodes-stitch-test-problem), but both of them make the instance follow the tangent of the curve.
Here's my current setup: [image]

Comment: Would this geometry nodes tutorial by Joey Carlino help? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T_ZzO86dBIA

Comment: Have you already tried this variant? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/259117/145249

Comment: Hey @JohnEason I've tried this after you mentioned it, it uses the vector tangent, so sadly it doesn't work for me

Comment: Hey @quellenform, I tried it and it also didn't work

Comment: Ok. Worth a try! :^(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version subtracts the *Position* at *Index* of the resampled curve from the *Position* at *Index* +1, and uses that vector to align the instance at *Index*:

[image]

The *Length* of that vector could be used to stretch (*Scale*) the instances exactly between points, if that's what you wanted.

[image]

If you sometimes had to deal with cyclic curves, that would additionally require a *Switch* on *Is Cyclic*, to include an instance on the curve's last point.

The stretch and cyclic features are included in the .blend:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Very similar to Fred's answer, just another approach:

[image]

Here I simply subdivide the curve with `Subdivide Curve`, then transfer the tangents of the preceding points back to the points at which an instantiation is to take place, and ultimately use these tangents to create a rotation for the instances.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

Answer (score 2):

May be another approach will work for you, it's less elegant for sure but any way.

Just resample the curve 2 times, the first is the curve definition you need (d), now resample it a second time by (2*d)-1, it will give you intermediates points in the center of the segment obtain with the first resample. Then use Curve to points. Now you must delete all the points made with the first resample they are odd so you can easily select them with a modulo.

[image]

I hope it will help.

**Edit:** I have change the .blend, now the length of the instances match the length segment, almost...

[image]

Comment: This one almost works, but the moment you have something that's not the right length it goes wrong.

Comment: Ok, I try to edit the blend with the right length this time...